# why output is now showing of python program in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

hello I am new in python.. installed Visual Studio Code s/w but output now showing see in the screenshot, I tried to change the theme but did not show output
[image: look here]

```py
# This program adds two numbers

num1 = 1.5
num2 = 6.3

# Add two numbers
sum = float(num1) + float(num2)

# Display the sum
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

Comment: Make sure to save your file (ctrl+s). The little circle near your file name indicate a not saved file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't saved your file.

If you look at the bar with the file name, you will se a white circle.

[image]

That means that your file isn't saved.

Save your file and it will work.